# How to optimize Oracle request with clusters?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I need to optimise a request using clusters (on Oracle) but I'm having trouble understanding the documentation.

This is the request :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3 
WHERE TABLE1.col1=TABLE3.col3
AND TABLE2.col1=TABLE3.col4
AND TABLE1.col2=1
```

I understand that I have to create a cluster using something like this

```
CREATE CLUSTER cluster_1(col2 INTEGER)
```

and then create a table using that cluster

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1_CLUSTER
```

but the fact that i'm using 3 different tables is confusing me.

Comment: Clusters are an unusual option for query optimization.  A cluster is a different way of organizing a table, and allows multiple tables to be stored together and hash lookups of values.  Is there a reason you can't use indexes instead?  Indexes are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be written like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 JOIN
     TABLE3
     ON TABLE1.col1 = TABLE3.col3 JOIN
     TABLE2
     ON TABLE2.col1 = TABLE3.col4
WHERE TABLE1.col2 = 1;
```

The normal approach for optimization would be to use indexes:

- `TABLE1(col2, col1)`
- `TABLE3(col3, col4)`
- `TABLE2(col1)`